# Why is my innner loop being skipped after the first time?

Tags: javascript, loops, break

I have the following JS code:

```
var i = 0, j = 0;
for (j; j < 5; j++) {
innerloop:
  while (i < 5) {
    if (i === 3) {
      break innerloop;
    console.log("inner: " + i);
  }
  console.log("outer: " + j);
}
```

What I want to happen is for the inner loop to be executed 3 times (for 0, 1, 2), then the inner loop to be stopped and the outer loop to be continued, so that every time the outer loop is executed the inner loop is also executed 3 times.

However, although the outer loop is executed 5 times just as wanted the inner loop is only executed a total of 3 times, for the first time the outer loop is executed.

How am I able to make it so the inner loop runs every time the outer loop is run and not just the first time?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, I think what you need to do is reset `i` to 0 each time you reach `innerloop`.

Comment: You'll need to reset `I`

Comment: Your snippet is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset using `i = 0` after breaking out of the innerLoop

Comment: `i` is always 0. Looks like an infinite loop to me.